# Testing ehcache @Cacheable

Tags: java, spring, junit, ehcache

In testing ehcache I've written below code in order to test :

```
package ehcache;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:spring-ehcache.xml")
public class TestEhcache {

    @Test
    public void testCache(){

        tester();
        tester();
        tester();

    }

    @Cacheable(value = "myCache")
    public String tester(){

        return "test";
    }

}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
     xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">
    <cache:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager"
        p:cache-manager-ref="ehcache" />
    <bean id="ehcache"
        class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean"
        p:config-location="my-ehcache.xml" />
</beans>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd">
    <defaultCache eternal="true" maxElementsInMemory="100" overflowToDisk="false" />
    <cache name="myCache" maxElementsInMemory="10000" eternal="true" overflowToDisk="false" />
</ehcache>
```

But return value of method `tester` is invoked multiple times. Have I wired the cache correctly ?

Comment: I think that your  @Cacheable annotation is ommited during test class initialisation. If you put cachable annotation on method which belong to class initialised by spring context is the behavior the same ?

Comment: @Josef Procházka yes that was the issue, once I moved the cacheable method to Spring managed bean it works as expected.